# Possible to hide #define / Macros in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some code that I instrumented with stopwatches in order to log where execution time is going.  I don't want to always run it, so I thought that the most efficient way to handle the timers involves using pre-processor macros.  For the example below, if `ENABLE_ENGR_PROFILING` is defined, I call the start() function on the stopwatch, do some work, then call accumulate() on the stopwatch which takes the time delta measured from start() and adds it to the time counter.  Then at the end of the program, I can dump the time and see where time went.  This works well, but it adds a lot of code.  I don't want to be distracted by the timer code when I am working on the algorithm.  Of the 7 lines below, I really only want to see 1 line, `someTimeConsumingCode()` when I am working on my program.  Is there a way to hide these macros in Visual Studio 2010?

```
#if defined(ENABLE_ENGR_PROFILING)
stopwatch.start();  
#endif
someTimeConsumingCode();
#if defined(ENABLE_ENGR_PROFILING)
stopwatch.accumulate(); 
#endif
```

Comment: What do you mean by "working on the algorithm"?

Comment: By algorithm, I mean everything besides the timers...I would like to ignore the timers (not see them) when working on the algorithm / main program code.

Comment: Can you move up to 2012 or 2013? Lambda make this sort of thing nicer than macros...

Comment: @486DX2-66 - So how does the distraction occur?

Comment: You can collapse the if blocks using the visual studio outlining feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hide the code completely, but you can define some macros to clean up the clutter:

```
#if defined(ENABLE_ENGR_PROFILING)
#define DECLARE_STOPWATCH() TStopWatch stopwatch; // <- whatever your class type actually is
#define START_STOPWATCH() stopwatch.start()
#define ACCUMULATE_STOPWATCH() stopwatch.accumulate()
#else
#define DECLARE_STOPWATCH()
#define START_STOPWATCH()
#define ACCUMULATE_STOPWATCH()
#endif
```

```
DECLARE_STOPWATCH();
...
START_STOPWATCH();
someTimeConsumingCode();
ACCUMULATE_STOPWATCH();
```